# Return button name from button id - is this possible?

Tags: android

Can you use a widget's @id to get the String value of its @string/ value?

I have a button with an id

```
R.id.note_on
```

its corresponding string has the id

```
R.string.button_note_on
```

the value of this string is "Note On"

I'd like to use R.id.note_on to return the "Note On" string associated with that button - I've tried various things but no luck. I can use other means to get the desired result, just curious whether this is possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.note_on);
btn.getText().toString();
```

That's the only way.

Comment: why has this been down-voted? If I understand the question correctly, this is exactly the answer!